# Are the different XBee SX 900 RF modules compatible with each other?

Tags: rf, xbee, certification

I am looking at the different XBee SX 900 modules offered by Digi and noticed that there are many versions of the same module which are certified for use in different countries/regions.

Is there any physical difference between these modules or is the only difference certification with different regulators in different regions?

Specifically, I am interested in the XB9X-DMUS-001 (USA version) vs the XB9X-DMUS-031 (New Zealand). If I am not concerned with certification status, are these parts interchangeable?

Comment: You might read the data sheets that relate to the individual items and make comparisons. Carrier frequency range might vary. Power outputs might vary.

Comment: @Andyaka Thank you for your comment. That's the thing. I can't find any documentation that shows any differences between the region models. From what I can see, they are identical. but I'm not sure.